# .htaccess RewriteRule to work with hidden and visible GETs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here what I've already done.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?file=$1
```

So when visiting `domain.com/browse` it actually reads `domain.com/index.php?file=browse`

But the problem is, this does not pass visible GET variables like this: `domain.com/browse?page=2`. How do I make it pass both GET variables: `domain.com/index.php?file=browse&page=2`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```
RewriteRule ^browse/?$ index.php?file=browse&page=1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^browse/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?file=browse&page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

#else it's for files
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

or use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ php.php?file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

the QSA (Query String Append) flag will allow passing _GET vars

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are multiple 'file's and also there are multiple GET variables. So I thought not to add every one of them as a RewriteRule.

Comment: I would agree yes it will be painful and not efficient. The second rule as the same effect as Mathieu's answer.

Comment: Totally forgot about the QSA flag, nice one.

Comment: So... what would be the best way?

Comment: I prefer the QSA because it's easier to read and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` is also good to use. I think it's a matter of personal preferences.

Answer (score 7):

You must add the query string explicitly in your rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?file=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```